# Filter Pivot Table based on Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter a Pandas pivot table based on a Pandas dataframe. For example:

df1

```
test_id                 gene
ENSMUSG00000000001.4    Gnai7
ENSMUSG00000000003.15   Pbsa
ENSMUSG00000000028.14   Cdc4
```

pt1

```
condition               CAS     CAS     CAS
replicate               0       1       2
tracking_id                                                 
ENSMUSG00000000001.4    45.25   46.55   49.88
ENSMUSG00000000028.14   1.51    1.63    1.62
ENSMUSG00000000031.15   16.99   17.54   18.69
```

output

```
condition               CAS     CAS     CAS     gene
replicate               0       1       2
tracking_id                                                 
ENSMUSG00000000001.4    45.25   46.55   49.88   Gnai7
ENSMUSG00000000028.14   1.51    1.63    1.62    Cdc4
```

The [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method seems like a potential solution by using the `test_id` and `tracking_id` as keys. Although I'm not sure how to also include the `gene` column in the output too.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
pt1.merge(df1, how=left, left_on='condition', right_on ='test_id')
```

Comment: Thanks, in testing this returns: `KeyError: 'condition'`. The pt1.columns are: 
`MultiIndex(levels=[['CAS', 'TET', 'WT', 'mean'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, '']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 6]],
           names=['condition', 'replicate'])`

Comment: Ok, try `pt1.merge(df1, how=left, left_index=True, right_on ='test_id')`

Comment: I think we're getting closer. The output is column-based instead of a pivot table: `,"('CAS', 0)","('CAS', 1)","('CAS', 2)","('TET', 0)","('TET', 1)","('TET', 2)","('TET', 3)","('TET', 4)","('TET', 5)","('WT', 0)","('WT', 1)","('WT', 2)","('mean', '')",test_id,gene,significant`. Is it possible to maintain the pivot table?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can do that with merge. Could you add the gene column to your dataframe before you pivot the data?